# difference between calling method as static and as class method through reflection

Tags: java

I have a line of code like this:

```
ConfiguationManagerUtils.class.getResource(resourceName);
```

I don't understand why reflection is used here. What is the difference between calling it like a static class method:

```
ConfiguationManagerUtils.getResource(resourceName);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not using reflection at all. The `getResource(String)` method called in your first snippet simply isn't declared on `ConfigurationManagerUtils` - it's declared on the `Class` class, as an instance method. If the second code snippet works as well, that's because there's a static `getResource(String)` method declared in `ConfigurationManagerUtils` (or a superclass). That may well do something *entirely different* to `Class.getResource()`.

The first snippet is just using a class literal (`ConfigurationManagerUtils.class`) to obtain a reference to a `Class` instance on which it can call the [`getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) instance method.

Comment: Thanks, actually there's a method called `getResource` and it's static defined for `ConfigurationManagerUtils`, that's probably what confused me. Is this a normal practice to access `Class` instance like this? And how can I distinguish it from reflection, which also uses `class` after class names?

Comment: @Maximus: It's common to use `Class.getResource` to access resources, yes. And as for distinguishing it from reflection - reflection involves discovering and invoking members (e.g. methods or constructors) in classes. Not *everything* in the `Class` type counts as reflection...

Answer (score 2):

In this code you call a non-static method of object `Class` referring to your `ConfiguationManagerUtils` class:

```
ConfiguationManagerUtils.class.getResource(resourceName);
```

In this code you call a static method of your `ConfiguationManagerUtils` class.

```
ConfiguationManagerUtils.getResource(resourceName);
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't using reflection, you're just accessing the `class` attribute of `ConfiguationManagerUtils`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a *BIG* difference between the 2 calls.

> 1. ConfiguationManagerUtils.class.getResource(resourceName);
>      the method `getResource()` of the *class-object* of `ConfiguationManagerUtils` is called. Not the one you define *inside the class ConfiguationManagerUtils*.
> 2. ConfiguationManagerUtils.getResource(resourceName); 
>      The methode from the class `ConfiguationManagerUtils` is called. i.e,
>      the method is defined in the *code* inside class
>      `ConfiguationManagerUtils`.